Gradle - Circular dependency when depending on other submodule
Hay there,
I'm currently trying to organize my Lib Project a bit better by seperating it into multiple modules.
Right now I got 2 Modules:

network
storage

Both modules got those subprojects:

common
fabric
neoforge

So my Project structure looks like this:
lib
 ├── network
 │   ├── common
 │   ├── fabric
 │   └── neoforge
 └── storage
     ├── common
     ├── fabric
     └── neoforge

The :storage:common module depends on the :network:common module which is why i added
dependencies {
    implementation(project(path: ":network:common", configuration: 'namedElements')) { transitive false }
}

to my :storage:common build.gradle file. Building my project with that dependency results into an
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:storage:common:classes
\--- :storage:common:compileJava
     \--- :storage:common:jar
          +--- :storage:common:classes (*)
          \--- :storage:common:compileJava (*)

error which only made sense to me after taking a look into the project dependency tree where intellij tells me that the :storage:common depends on itself instead of :network:common somehow.
I got no idea why this happens and what to change to fix that. It would be awesome if someone could help me out here :)

I have no idea if it's feasible in you specific case, but im my projects a package common is usually... well, ... how can I say... common...
lib
 |--- common
 ├── network
 │   ├── fabric
 │   └── neoforge
 └── storage
     ├── fabric
     └── neoforge

If I want to keep (for any reasons) the structure :network:common and :storage:common I have to make sure that any line of code inside :network:common is only used in the network module and any line of code inside :storage:common is only used in the storage module.
I think you need some refactoring. Usually circular dependecies means simply just that.
